# Center an image and the crop it to a fixed pixel size (java)

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, snapshot

I'm currently working on a project were the user can draw an image and a small neural network then guesses the drawn(in Java, trust me I wanted to do it in Python).
For this, I exported the canvas using snapshot. Now I want to center and crop a to a fixed size, let's say 50x50 pixel. Does Java have any methods for this?

```
public void guess(ActionEvent actionevent) {

    SnapshotParameters params = new SnapshotParameters();
    params.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    WritableImage image = new WritableImage((int)canvas.getWidth(),(int)canvas.getHeight());
    image = canvas.snapshot(params, null);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage((int)image.getWidth(),(int)image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    bufferedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
    String str = NNInterface.initNN(bufferedImage);
    outputText.setText(str);
}
```

}

Else I'd had to use double arrays or smth.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> crop a to a fixed size, let's say 50x50 pixel. Does Java have any methods for this?

Hmm, in your question you use the `BufferedImage` tag and the `Image` tag.

In the `BufferedImage` class you find the `getSubimage(...)` method, which would allow you to crop the image.

In the `Image` class you find the `getScaledInstance(...)` method, which allows you to scale the image.

One would assume you read the API before asking a question. Maybe I don't understand the question?

Comment: I read it but maybe I misunderstood these two methods. I will look into it. Thx !